# How to install libpng12-0 in Ubuntu20.10

Tags: libpng

I tried to install libpng12 on Ubuntu, but all failed. I tried sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12，But the problem arises when I enter sudo apt install libpng12-0

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source

> E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello. A Google search of the name of the file you are trying to install brings up this site. https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/fix-libpng12-0-missing-in-ubuntu-1804.html This would be a good place for you to start.

Comment: I've read this article, but I still can't: (, is it the problem of Open source mirror station? I've tried，but,,It doesn't work！！

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is not anymore supported, and the mirrors for the repositories have been deactivated.  Fresh install either 20.04 or 21.10

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu.
The problem is that the repositories are deactivated because the Ubuntu 20.10 is EndOfLife (EOL). Consider reinstalling 20.04 (LTS) or 21.10 if you want support and/or a secure Operating System.